# How to make a person be given a role, discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

For example, a person mentions the role of @role1 and the bot gives him this role. How to do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Did you run into any errors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

For the rewrite branch:

```py
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="role to add name")
user = ctx.message.author
await user.add_roles(role)
```

For the async branch:

```py
user = ctx.message.author
role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="role to add name")
await client.add_roles(user, role)
```

Comment: no, the user mentions a role, for example @blue and the bot should give him this role, or another user mention role of red and the bot should also give him the role of red

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good solution. Just make it so it requires a role, or a role mention.

We basically make a command where it requires two arguments: a role, and a mentioned member. You can configure this to make it so only administrators can run this command. If the Role doesn't exist, it will send a "This is not a correct role" message. Let me know if you face any issues!

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents=intents, case_intensitive=True)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is online!')

@client.command()
async def addrole(ctx, user: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
    try:
        await user.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} was given the role: {role.name}')
    except commands.BadArgument:
        await ctx.send('That is not a correct role!')

client.run('TOKEN')
```